# Check in comments missing in Office 365 workflow

Tags: workflow, office, item, check-in

I am trying to get Check-in comments from SharePoint forms library with versioning enabled but in the workflow there is no option of "Check in item " showing in workflow current item.

Answer (score 0):

You can find Check in/Check out under ... > More > in order to check it in. If you want a workflow for that behavior you can create it using one of the out of the box workflows like 'Request manager approval for a selected item'.